# adding item to attribute with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got this list of div with predefined data-groups. I would like to add a data-groups item called "my" with jquery by means of check sign in a checkbox (and remove with uncheck).

```
<div class="item yellow" data-kpi="one" data-res="9" data-ref="3" data-groups='["all", "numbers", "red", "square"]'><input type="checkbox" name="add" value="my" /></div>
<div class="item yellow" data-kpi="two" data-res="9" data-ref="3" data-groups='["all", "numbers", "green", "circel"]'><input type="checkbox" name="add" value="my" /></div>
```

Comment: Post, What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried appending to the data-groups but that doesn't work.

Comment: add a JSFiddle please

Comment: Post your non-working code that will be enough

Comment: @mark what are you trying to do ?

Comment: it works like a charm see the fiddle it your code - http://jsfiddle.net/fvGUx/2/

Comment: @mark are you clear or any other issue let me know

Comment: works indeed. thanks sudharsan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. See the fiddle demo and watch console

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {

     if($(this).is(":checked")){
         $(this).parent().data("groups").push("my");
         console.log($(this).parent().data("groups"))
      }
      else{
         $(this).parent().data("groups").pop();
          console.log($(this).parent().data("groups"))
       }

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fvGUx/3/)

Comment: I have changed the code in my original post. Adding works fine, but removing is not working. So far you helped my a lot. Thank you for that.

Comment: It is working fine. If you want the changes to reflect in DOM, use `attr()`